# Filepond used only as enchancement to input file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filepond

Is there a way to configure Filepond to work only as an enhancement for the input file element? For now, I want to use it as a drop-in upgrade to my form that handles upload with PHP backend.

When I upload a file the input element is briefly populated with the file data then it is removed and that breaks my form validation and standard upload method. Is there a way to bypass it or should I change my upload and validation to work inherently with Filepond?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer and it is very straightforward.

I use `FilePond:addfile` event, get the file that was uploaded and pass it directly into the input using DataTransfer API.

```
const pond = document.querySelector('.filepond--root');

pond.addEventListener('FilePond:addfile', e => {

    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    dt.items.add(e.detail.file.file);

    let fi = e.target.querySelector('input');
    fi.files = dt.files;
});
```

Comment: Please note that this only works on Firefox and Chrome → https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/